# Making WearableListenerService onDataChanged() call on every PutDataMapRequest

Tags: android, wear-os

I want WearableListenerService to call onDataChanged() every time I make a request. I am aware that onDataChanged() is only called, well, on data change and not every time.

I can add dummy data with the date to make this happen, but that feels patchy.

Is there a more elegant way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: What do you mean by 'every time I make a request?'

Comment: I mean that I will get to onDataChange() every time I call Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(), regardless of if it is the same. I would have used the MessgeAPI, but it seems that the payload limitation is lower than the one the DataAPI has, and I need to pass an Asset (which makes it crash using the MessageAPI as mentioned in my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669318/wear-getting-indexoutofbounds-exception-from-datamap-frombytearraymessageeven)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to turn the situation around a bit. As you say, `onDataChanged` is only called whenever there's a change and you should probably keep handling that.

Whenever you need to know the current value you can use one of the `Wearable.DataApi.getDataItem`(s) methods as described on https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataApi.html .