# Wear - getting IndexOutOfBounds exception from DataMap.fromByteArray(messageEvent.getData());

Tags: android, wear-os

In my app, I want to use the MessageAPI to communicate between my phone and my wear device.
To send data, I use DataMap:

Sending a message from my phone:

```
MessageApi.SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(
                googleApiClient, nodes.get(0), SharedConstants.Paths.PATH_WEAR_NOTIFICATION, dataMap.toByteArray()).await();
```

Reading the message on the wear device (WearableListenerService, onMessageReceived()):

```
    byte[] data = messageEvent.getData();
    DataMap dataMap = DataMap.fromByteArray(data); <--- crashes
```

I get the exception:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: WearableListenerService
    Process: com.aaa.bbb, PID: 20375
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.pb.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.pb.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataMap.fromByteArray(Unknown Source)
            at com.aaa.bbb.services.NotificationWearableListenerService.onMessageReceived(NotificationWearableListenerService.java:74)
            at com.google.android.gms.wearable.WearableListenerService$a$2.run(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

However, the byte array is not empty.

Does anyone know why can this happen?

**Edit:**

After testing this a bit more, I noticed that once I remove an image from the payload, the crash stopped. Using the same payload is working when using the DataAPI.
Is the limitation for the MessageAPI specified in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi.html#sendMessage(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20byte[])) 100 kilobit or kilobyte?

Comment: Have you already found how to fix this? I have the same problem now.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I used the DataAPI instead of the MessageAPI even though it does not feel right